# Login Table structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database 'practice'.I`m trying to make database that allows users to Login and submit data in forms.

The admin adds the username and the password for few users.The users then login using the password and username.

Now Since the admin adds users his functions must be different from the users and a different page is to be loaded for him so to identify admin.I have added the following admin column in the table.

```
authenticate table
username | password | admin
----------------------------
admin    | 7821y34n | 1
 007     |  435432  | 0
```

admin is of type tinyint `if 1 then admin if 0 then user` 
Is this the way to create an authenticate table?

Comment: Looks good, though I wouldn't get in the habit of storing passwords in plain text.  Also, if you have too many roles or want to associate more than one role with a user, you might want to make a `Roles` table which can map a role to a user.

Comment: yes if you only have two types this will work fine. alternatively you can have user_type_id as foreign key which references another table like user_types for multiple user levels. encrypt passwords though

Comment: @ Mike and Sam  Yes I am going through a few SO Q/A for Password  encryption.I have a small issue though with the second table user_details.'

Comment: Now the second table needs the username column as well to update the name and other values related to non admin users so how should I create a column? Inserting usernames again will cause data redundancy can You explain how to use foreign keys in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good practice is to map a `ROLE` table to a `USER` table this way a user could have multiple roles.

For your second question as I sayed in the comments I would put all data in the `user` table but if you need to separate data in two tables you could do it this way.

Just by mapping `user_details` table to the `user` table. (`user_id` in `user_details`)

Table **USER**

```
ID | USERNAME | PASSWORD  
-------------------------
1  | bill     | 09hk4352  /* password should be encoded */
2  | frank    | 7dfs3454
```

Table **USER_DETAILS**

```
ID | DOB         | USER_ID      
------------------------
2  | 1988-05-12  | 1
```

Table **ROLE**

```
ID | ROLE 
---------------
1  | ROLE_USER 
2  | ROLE_ADMIN  
3  | ROLE_GUEST
```

Table **USER_ROLE**

```
ROLE_ID | USER_ID
------------------
1       | 2 /* user "frank" has ROLE_USER */
2       | 2 /* user "frank" has also ROLE_ADMIN */
1       | 1 /* user "bill" has ROLE_USER */
```

Comment: the second table needs the username column as well to update the name and other values related to non admin users so how should I create a column? Inserting usernames again will cause data redundancy can You explain how to use foreign keys in this case

Comment: I don't understand your question could you be more clear please ?

Comment: I have a second table user_details the table also needs a username column (non admin users).currently all usernames are added by admin.adding the same usernames in the second table is not correct so how do i do this using foreign keys?can you please explain

Comment: Could you update your post with the `user_details`structure ?

Comment: I have added 2nd table now

Comment: I think you don't actually need the USER_ROLE table, it's overkill/overhead. It will not work well when you have to do 5 `JOIN`s. Instead, you can just have the ROLE_ID column in the USER table.

Comment: @AAB you don't need two separate tables you can have all the user informations in the USER table. If you really needs another table then you shoud map the user table with the user_details table adding the user id in the table user_details. Ask another question for this if you want.

Comment: remove the `user_details` table in your question and ask another question since it is a different question.

Comment: @daguru I do require a different table as the form data will increase can you give an example to map this in your current answer I will edit my question